# Update only a part of screen with texture and renderer?

Tags: c, sdl-2

I'm trying to display a char array in a texture in the form of a table. It works well but now I'd like to dynamically modify some char in the array (values in the table) without reloading the entire renderer.

I tried using `SDL_RenderClear` and `SDL_RenderPresent` again but it cleared the entire window.

How can I select only a part of my table and change it without modifying all the rest?

```
void draw_battlefield(t_env *e, int origin_x, int origin_y, int width, int height)
{
int j;
float x;
float y;
SDL_Color color = {255, 0, 0, 0};
SDL_Surface *surface;
SDL_Texture *texture;
int texW = 0;
int texH = 0;
SDL_Rect dstrect;

j = -1;
x = (float)origin_x;
y = origin_y;
while (++j < 4096)
{
    surface = TTF_RenderText_Solid(e->font_nb, base((unsigned char)e->battlefield[j]), color);
    texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(e->renderer, surface);
    texW = 0;
    texH = 0;
    SDL_QueryTexture(texture, NULL, NULL, &texW, &texH);
    dstrect = fill_rect((int)x, (int)y, &texW, &texH);
    x += ((float)width / 64);
    SDL_RenderCopy(e->renderer, texture, NULL, &dstrect);
    if ((j & 0x3f) == 0x3f)
    {
        x = (float)origin_x;
        y += ((float)height / 64);
    }
    SDL_DestroyTexture(texture);
    SDL_FreeSurface(surface);
}
}
```

Comment: Redrawing screen each frame is completely normal.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to refresh only a part of a screen, you can use *viewports*.
A citation from [lazyfoo.net](http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/09_the_viewport/index.php) tutorials that just says everything:

> Some times you only want to render part of the screen for things like minimaps. Using the viewport you can control where you render on the screen.

See [`SDL_RenderGetViewport`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_RenderGetViewport) and and [`SDL_RenderSetViewport`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_RenderSetViewport) for more details about how to set and get a viewport associated with the given render.

The basic idea is that an user can set a rectangle to which to render and the coordinates will be intended as relative to the rectangle. If you want to update only a texture without refreshing the entire window, put it in a viewport thus and that's all.